# How to get the public data of google+ and also how to post from my site to google+ using php

Tags: php, google-plus

Authentication between my site and google plus is working fine. But my details and my activities are not showing now.
we get getAccessToken of Googleplus like

```
{"access_token":"ya29.AHES6ZSTauVKgrdDUJLz1bZlk0ma3ETCKl3YiYsEHQkDQ36PyrllGQ","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3600,"id_token":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJhY2NvdW50cy5nb29nbGUuY29tIiwiYXVkIjoiNDAwNjIzMTI2NjM3LmFwcHMuZ29vZ2xldXNlcmNvbnRlbnQuY29tIiwiY2lkIjoiNDAwNjIzMTI2NjM3LmFwcHMuZ29vZ2xldXNlcmNvbnRlbnQuY29tIiwiaWQiOiIxMDUzODYwMjMyMTg3NTcyNDAzMTIiLCJ0b2tlbl9oYXNoIjoiQTN5cGdINzRhWUpERklqY0lMSW1vdyIsImlhdCI6MTMyNzM4NzQ4MiwiZXhwIjoxMzI3MzkxMzgyfQ.bwU8dg4KKEYkTfpXMPJIdMges2FKWaRcCq-65awk1s1pEELR1PtbnmVWYvONR9iweSBWeC3M5xWTruBeaxUxPvd9kMXIwRpdsKglXaDYucJaRvSl8T1SqCDpJJyuU8Lkx6qR5ge2rrVNAr_bBjOzexrwM3KaAyUNbt0SVmSLpug","refresh_token":"1\/soWfHkCkkT0upeXArWljaqkg3tmehIOtT7Hkt0Wi3PQ","created":1327387715}
```

But when we try to print my details or my public activities of google+ using php
It displays nothing.
And Also I wanna post

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using the PHP API?

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/

If you have, you might consider posting your actual code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't post to the Google+ API. It is currently read only.