# Is there any php api for google + like facebook graph api?

Tags: php, google-plus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the public data of google+ and also how to post from my site to google+ using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8983632/how-to-get-the-public-data-of-google-and-also-how-to-post-from-my-site-to-googl)

Using facebook graph api, we can post on users wall. Like this, Is there any api for google+ to access their basic profile details / to post on their wall (I dont know whether it is called wall in g+ :) )?

Answer (score 1):

1st result on Google for "Google+ api":

https://developers.google.com/+/api/

Comment: Thanks for the link. Can i post on users wall? It seems i can get their profile details. Is there any php example coding? Or should i use the curl?

Comment: This really isn't meant to sound as bad as it probably will, please can you read things before asking stupid questions? If you waste people's time, they're less likely to help you in future (in a form of ['crying wolf'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crying_wolf) anaology).  At the top of the link I provided (which I found after a single Google search), it says 'Note: The Google+ API currently provides read-only access to public data. All API calls require either an OAuth 2.0 token or an API key.'.  Another single Google search gives lots of questions on here with exactly the same question.